# Angularjs: how to extend Javascript class?

Tags: angularjs, prototype

I'm writing my first new Angularjs project.

I need to add my custom method (say, `addHours()`), to a javascript class, say `Date()`.
For completeness, this is my (working) method:

```
Date.prototype.addHours = function(h) {
  this.setHours(this.getHours() + parseInt(h));
  return this;
}
```

Which is the recommended way to do it? Where to put the prototype functions, so they are available through all my project? Should I better create a new Date class? Should I better define an angular service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [this article](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/angular-model-objects-with-javascript-classes-2e6a067c73bc) can give you some insight.

Additionally, you could just include that snippet in a JS file on your index.html which would make all Date objects in your application have `addHours`. I tend to do this for any standard library 'enhancements' so I can easily identify where the standard library objects deviate.

**Update**:

A concrete example following along with the article, for the most part:

```
yourApp.factory( 'MyDate', function() {

    //Constructor
    function MyDate( date ) {
        this.date = date; //Wrapping a JS date object.
        //Probably want to add some safety here to make sure it IS a date obj
    }

    MyDate.prototype.addHours( h ) {
        this.date.setHours( this.date.getHours() + parseInt(h) );
    }

    return MyDate;
});

yourApp.controller( 'MyDateController', function( $scope, MyDate ) {

   $scope.someMethod = function(h) {
       //Some trigger, UI or what not
       $scope.myDate = new MyDate( new Date() );
       $scope.myDate.addHours(h);
       //Do something with the new date
   };
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the article does not explain how to add a prototype to a javascript class like Date() (or perhaps I did not understand how to do it... :-(). About including a js snippet file to my project, yes, that's my current solution, but I would prefer a more 'angular' one... :-) (and more grunt-integrated...).

Comment: My intention was you could wrap a Date object in a custom object via an angular factory, like the article's first code snippet with `User`. That would be "more angular" but you'll just have to inject that dependency wherever you need it. Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't think the article completely fulfills my request... I would like to use 'Date' class directly, and not indirectly, like - say - `Util.myDate.addHours()` (if I do correctly understand the article's meaning...).

Comment: If you want to use it directly and add custom functionality, I think you're stuck with the 2nd paragraph's solution. What the `Date` object, or any standard object does, is outside the scope of angularjs, unless it's a custom object in which case you should be wrapping it in a factory. Maybe you could use other JS libraries that handle time more akin to what you need?

Comment: Do you mean something like `MyDate.prototype = new Date();` ? But, how do I define my prototype functions? And, where do I put this code? Could you please write a simple example?

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it helps! And to answer where you put it, wherever you think it's reasonable to put your common-use factories. If it's a small application, next to your app declaration is probably fine.

Comment: Thanks! The code makes perfectly sense... Altough the new myClass(new Class()) completely misses one of the prototyping best features: to add a behavior to an existing class... I suppose I will fall back - as you suggested - on a pure javascript snippet sourced from my index.html... Not so angular, but it works... :-) I'll wait some hours more before accepting your answer, but I suppose it's the only possible solution... :-(

Comment: The benefit to `new myClass(new Class())` here though is you won't trample on the standard libraries. I'm pretty sure other libraries like jQuery, _, prototype, all do something similar to this so you can use the enhanced version without ruining the standard one since that could cause unpredictable issues. Either way, glad you found a solution you like!

Comment: I don't like it so much, really... :-( However, I was not looking for a solution to this particular problem, but a solution for the general problem of extending JS classes, in an Angular way... I suppose your suggestion is a good solution, but it completely looses the 'beauty' of prototypes (in your solution you could even avoid using a prototype, and use a regular method, right?)...

Comment: Hmmm... Sorry... Just trying your solution... This is my factory:
`app.factory('DateTime', function () {

  // class constructor
  function DateTime(date) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]') { // date is a Date object
      this.date = date;
    } else { // date is not a Date object
      this.date = new Date(date);
    }
  }
});
`
but, when using it:

  `$scope.dt = new DateTime();`

(and I did inject it, yes... :-), I get:

  `Error: DateTime is not a constructor`...

am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you could just use a regular function and not a prototype. `DateTime()` isn't. `DateTime(obj)` is though. Either pass in a parameter or create a constructor for `DateTime()` with no params.

Comment: It make perfect sense, as always... Though, `$scope.dt = new DateTime(new Date());` gives the same error... :-(

Comment: Also created a DateTime constructor with no params, same result... :-(

Comment: Ahah! So I looked back over the article's example and missed a critical line. See my updated answer. Note the added return in the factory.

Comment: Yuppp! Perfect. One more question (sorry!!!): What if I need a real date object in my view (say: `ng-model="dt"`), to be used - for example - by datepicker? (probably I should better revert to the prototypes file solution... :-()

Comment: So, I had to do something fancy like this with a custom file chooser I made. I suggest that you 'hide' the real datepicker input field and next to the button display your own. When a date is picked, listen for the update, set your model, and then set your custom field to the value (formatted however you want). Without knowing more this is all I can suggest at the moment. SO is also yelling at me to stop having extended discussions in comments! Post a new question after you've tried some things! And I'd love an accepted answer for this one! =D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58984/discussion-between-marcos-and-tony).